# search for words in an array of letters

Tags: java, arrays

I have a arrayList called dictionary which includes the following letters.
g,t,c,a,n,d,l,e,t,j,a,q.

I want the output to be for example, 
2candle
3and etc.
the number is an offset from the start of the array being searched.

I want the output be list of locations of matches, each consisting of an offset from the beginning of the text and the string found.
Please HELP!!

Comment: what happened to 2can?

Answer (score 0):

If we think about this type of problem, the key is to figure out all of the different possibilities there are for places where you will find a word. Here is the skeleton of a method that I wrote that would go about this process:

```
public static String findWords(final char[] characters) {
    String toRet = "";

    // First iterate through every character in the array characters.
    for (int i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {

        /*
         * Then at each step in this loop, check all possible word
         * combinations to see if it's a word. For example, check and see if
         * characters[i], characters[i+1] forms a word. Then check and see
         * if the word made by adding together characters[i],
         * characters[i+1], and characters[i+2] is a word. Then check and
         * see if the word formed by adding together the characters
         * characters[i], characters[i+1], characters[i+2], characters[i+3]
         * is a word.
         */

        // Doing the above requires a nested loop inside of the original
        // loop.
        for (int j = 0; j < characters.length - i; j++) {

            // When you do find a word that is formed, then go ahead and add
            // to your string toRet the details about the word formed.
        }
    }

    return toRet;
}
```

This doesn't fully answer your question, but I hope it

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, now I know how to start it and kinda know what to do!!